# Elecric field equations of motion

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry-breaking

I'm reading this paper [*Quantum Time Crystals,* Frank Wilczek, Center for Theoretical Physics,](http://arxiv.org/abs/1202.2539) about time crystals, and in the situation described there is a particle of unit mass and charge $q$, confined to a ring on which there is a current of $\frac{2\pi\alpha}{q}$.

> Abstract Quantum Time Crystals Frank Wilczek Center for Theoretical Physics arXiv:1202.2539v2  [quant-ph]  11 Jul 2012 Some subtleties and apparent diculties associated with the notion of spontaneous breaking of time translation symmetry in quantum mechanics are identied and resolved. A model exhibiting that phenomenon is displayed.

The paper states the Lagrangian and angular momentum of the particle to be:
 $$L=\frac{1}{2}\dot{\phi}^2+\alpha\dot{\phi}, \qquad 
\pi_\phi=\dot{\phi}+\alpha \tag{2}$$

---

1. My question is how these equations were developed? I understand basic analytical mechanics so I guess just electric part is new to me,
2. What is the parameter $\alpha$?

Comment: Hi proton I added an abstract, as people sometimes like to know more  before going off site, and you may consider explicity stating that a PDF download is involved, otherwise users will think your link is faulty. I did :). Best of luck with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lagrangian for a charged particle in a field is written [this way](http://www.phys.ufl.edu/~pjh/teaching/phy4605/notes/chargelagrangiannotes.pdf):

$$L=\frac{1}{2}m\dot{\boldsymbol{r}}\cdot\dot{\boldsymbol{r}}+q(\boldsymbol{A}\cdot\dot{\boldsymbol{r}}-\phi)$$

where $\boldsymbol{A}$ is the magnetic vector potential, and $\phi$ is the electric scalar potential. Now, given a magnetic flux $\Phi_{B}$, the magnetic vector potential can be obtained with the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_flux):

$$\Phi_{B}=\oint \boldsymbol{A}\cdot d\boldsymbol{l}$$

1. Notice that the paper you post, states that $2\pi\alpha/q$ is a flux
   passing through the ring, so in that
   case the vector potential would be like:

   $$A_{\varphi}=\Phi_{B}/2\pi$$

   where we are using the asumption that the ring has unit radius.
   Also, in the Lagrangian we would have $m=1$ and $\phi=0$ (there is
   no electric field). Because the particle is confined to the ring, it
   has only 1 degree of freedom, which can be  described by the
   coordinate $\varphi$. With all of this, you recover the Lagrangian
   given in the paper:

   $$L=\frac{1}{2}\dot{\varphi}^2+q\bigg(\frac{\Phi_{B}}{2\pi}\dot{\varphi}\bigg)=\frac{1}{2}\dot{\varphi}^2+\alpha\dot{\varphi}$$
2. I think the parameter $\alpha$ is exactly that... a parameter. Of course it must have the correct dimensions given by $\Phi_{B}=2\pi\alpha/q$.